# Use useMemo to meonize a function with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem with useState hook in React it is causing to many re renders and the app breaks. I am trying using useState set function inside a return that has a lot of renders.

I have found out i can use useMemo or useCallback hooks to memonize the function. The problem i am having pass a parameter to this function.

Somewhere in my code i am looking over a array and i want to call this function for every array item from the loop to process the data.

```
const myComponent = () => {
    
   const [example, setExample] = useState({});

   const myFunction = (item) => {
      setExample(item)
   }

    return (
        array.map(item => {
          const test = myFunction(item);
        
          <p>{test}</P
        })
    )
 }
```

SO the above is just example but how do i meonize `myFunction` since it takes a parameter i have tried:

```
const test = useMemo(item => setExample(item), [setExample]);
```

but when i then call `test(item)` in my map it does not work

Comment: Actually it's a bad practice. You're calling a function according to an Array length, so it may have huge items within. Please share more about what you want to do.

Comment: You want useCallback here. Or useMemo(() => item => …)

Comment: Yep that what i am trying to do but how do use memo or callback on a function that takes a parameter and needs to be called else where in the code. thx

Comment: Your app is broken because you set the state (are calling `setExample` from `myFunction`) **during rendering**. [Don't do that!](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#im-getting-an-error-too-many-re-renders) Memoising will help nothing. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Nope, that will not solve the problem

Comment: @Bergi OP's syntax is incorrect. `myFunction` is supposed to be a function in the body of the component (which actually breaks memorization). `myComponent` is the component body. I'll give it an edit.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Yeah, and thanks, but still memoisation will not solve the infinite rerendering problem

Comment: @Bergi !! I missed what was happening the `map`. Yes, that is the issue. I was too focused on the useCallback usage.

Comment: You dont clearly explained what do you want to do. I think - you dont need memo or useCallback. Clearly explain what do you want to do on logic level. Edit your question or reply here.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you write a useCallback memoized function that accepts a parameter;

```
const myFunction = useCallback((item) => {
 // Your logic here
}, []); // Your useCallback deps here
```

And here's how you call it;

```
myFunction(someItem)
```

Also, note that you should only use `useMemo` when you want to memoize the returned results e.g array, object etc. You should use `useCallback` when you want to memoize a function itself.

Answer (score -1):

First, let's talk about what `useCallback` is: it's a syntactic sugar for wrapping a function in use `useMemo`.

A normal usage of `useMemo` looks like this:

```
useMemo(() => n*n, [n]) // notice that it takes a function.
```

Then if you want to wrap a function, it becomes

```
useMemo(() => arg => { ... }, []) // notice that it takes a function.
```

`useCallback` simply shortens that to

```
useCallback(arg => { ... }, []) // notice that it takes a function.
```

With that out of the way, the issue you're facing is that you are declaring `myFunction` in the body of the function. It's identity changes on every render (it is redeclared every time).

A memorization like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
   const myFunc = (arg) => { }
   useCallback(myFunc, [myFunc])
}
```

will never work: `myFunc` changes every time, and the cached callback is not used.

To make it work, you need to extract `myFunc` out:

```
const myFunc = () => { }
function MyComponent() {
   useCallback(myFunc, [myFunc])
}
```

Now `myFunc` has a stable identity and can be memorized between renders.

Accordingly, your code should look like this:

```
const myFunction = (item, setExample) => { // Notice, we need to extract `setExample` into its own argument
   setExample(item)
}
```

```
const myComponent = () => {
    
   const [example, setExample] = useState({});

   const myMemoizedFunction = useCallback(myFunction, []) // `myFunction` never changes, it's a global constant

    return (
        array.map(item => {
          // This causes a rendering loop. Remove this!
          // const test = myMemoizedFunction(item, setExample);
        
          <p>{test}</P
        })
    )
 }
```